# How to redirect to a Facebook and Instagram app page on Xamarin

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.forms, instagram

I'm trying to redirect to a Facebook app page like this:

**code**

```
private void ExecuteEntrarFacebook()
{
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("fb://officialstackoverflow/11239244970"));
}
```

But it's redirecting to the feed page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link must be like this:

```
fb://page/pageid?referrer=app_link
```

Comment: Just "fb://page/11239244970" would do.